# Get date from one column based on the accumulating value of another column

Tags: r, date, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having a tough time figuring this out and I will try to explain where I need help the best I can.

I have a dataframe consisting of participant ID (column 1), possible dates of an appointment for that participant (column 2, ranging from V1 to V3, indicating that there are a maximum of three possible dates for each participant), the dates (column 3) and a column with values (column 4).
For each participant, we want to find one date for their appointment. The 2nd column (vis) indicates the preference of dates (V1 highest preference, if not possible then V2, if not possible then V3, if not possible then NO DATE). The possibility of getting each date depends on the value in column 4. if this column is equal to 60, then no more appointments on this date can be added. Each appointment made counts for a value of **2 to be added to this value**. So, for example, if date 2021-09-07 already has 60 as a value, then no more appointments can be added. But if date 2021-08-25 only has 44 as a value, a  maximum of 8 appointments can still be made for this date.

Example:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Included.y vis   date       ficol
       <dbl> <chr> <date>     <chr>
1        316 V1    2021-07-01 NA   
2       1027 V1    2021-07-01 NA   
3       1101 V1    2021-07-01 NA   
4         73 V1    2021-07-07 24   
5        479 V1    2021-07-07 24   
6       1026 V1    2021-07-07 24   
7       1186 V1    2021-07-07 24   
8         13 V2    2021-07-07 24   
9        139 V2    2021-07-07 24
```

Would become:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Included.y vis   date       ficol
       <dbl> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1        316 V1    2021-07-01     6
2       1027 V1    2021-07-01     6
3       1101 V1    2021-07-01     6
4         73 V1    2021-07-07    36
5        479 V1    2021-07-07    36
6       1026 V1    2021-07-07    36
7       1186 V1    2021-07-07    36
8         13 V2    2021-07-07    36
9        139 V2    2021-07-07    36
```

Since the column containing the values for 2021-07-01 used to be NA (meaning 0) and now 3 appointments take place on that date, the value in total becomes 6 (we are only interested in the total value since this will be the restriction (max 60)). For 2021-07-07 the value started out at 24, after 6 new appointments on that date, the value will be 36.
In this example everything turns out okay and the appointments can be scheduled but it could also be that the value of 2021-07-02 is already at a value of 58.

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Included.y vis   date       ficol
       <dbl> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1        317 V1    2021-07-02     58
```

This would then become:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Included.y vis   date       ficol
       <dbl> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1        317 V1    2021-07-02     60
```

And now the 2021-07-02 date is 'full' so no more appointments can fall on this date.

I really hope i made this as clear as possible. otherwise please let me know. I really hope you can help out!

I put the dput of the first 100 rows of the actual dataset here:

```
structure(list(Included.y = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 39L, 39L, 41L, 
42L, 42L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 
48L, 49L, 49L, 51L, 51L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 
59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 68L), 
    vis = c("V1", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V3", 
    "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", 
    "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", 
    "V3", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V3", 
    "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V2", "V1", "V3", 
    "V1", "V2", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
    "V1", "V2", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
    "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", 
    "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V2", "V1", "V3", "V1", 
    "V2", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2", 
    "V1"), date = structure(c(18865, 18864, 18928, 18927, 18919, 
    18920, 18918, 18942, 18941, 18878, 18879, 18877, 18963, 18962, 
    18857, 18858, 18856, 18897, 18898, 18970, 18969, 18814, 18815, 
    18813, 18942, 18941, 18921, 18920, 18851, 18850, 18911, 18912, 
    18911, 18912, 18822, 18823, 18821, 18865, 18864, 18953, 18954, 
    18813, 18814, 18962, 18963, 18961, 18869, 18830, 18829, 18827, 
    18828, 18935, 18934, 18954, 18955, 18953, 18955, 18956, 18954, 
    18862, 18863, 18904, 18911, 18912, 18911, 18912, 18822, 18823, 
    18821, 18926, 18927, 18925, 18844, 18843, 18914, 18913, 18984, 
    18983, 18956, 18955, 18949, 18948, 18878, 18879, 18877, 18813, 
    18991, 18990, 18967, 18968, 18857, 18858, 18856, 18967, 18968, 
    18869, 18870, 18918, 18919, 18954), class = "Date"), ficol = c(NA, 
    "44", " 4", "60", "20", NA, "60", NA, NA, "20", NA, "60", 
    NA, "52", NA, NA, "36", "60", "60", NA, NA, "60", "24", "60", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "16", "56", "16", "56", "16", "16", NA, 
    "60", NA, "44", "60", "60", "60", "60", "52", NA, "60", "60", 
    NA, NA, "60", "32", NA, "56", "60", NA, "60", NA, NA, "60", 
    "60", "60", "60", "56", "16", "56", "16", "16", NA, "60", 
    "60", "60", "60", NA, "16", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "44", 
    "20", NA, "60", "60", NA, NA, "60", "40", NA, NA, "36", "60", 
    "40", "60", "60", "60", "20", "60")), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`2` = 2L, 
`5` = 5L, `11` = 11L, `17` = 17L, `24` = 24L, `26` = 26L, `32` = 32L, 
`35` = 35L, `38` = 38L, `42` = 42L, `45` = 45L, `50` = 50L, `54` = 54L, 
`57` = 57L, `61` = 61L, `63` = 63L, `65` = 65L, `69` = 69L, `71` = 71L, 
`81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `84` = 84L, `87` = 87L, `90` = 90L, `98` = 98L, 
`101` = 101L, `104` = 104L, `107` = 107L, `110` = 110L, `115` = 115L, 
`117` = 117L, `119` = 119L, `123` = 123L, `129` = 129L, `132` = 132L, 
`135` = 135L, `150` = 150L, `155` = 155L, `159` = 159L, `161` = 161L, 
`163` = 163L, `165` = 165L, `167` = 167L, `171` = 171L, `173` = 173L, 
`178` = 178L, `180` = 180L, `186` = 186L, `199` = 199L, `201` = 201L, 
`207` = 207L, `209` = 209L, `219` = 219L, `223` = 223L, `225` = 225L, 
`228` = 228L, `231` = 231L, `233` = 233L, `238` = 238L, `240` = 240L, 
`243` = 243L, `249` = 249L, `251` = 251L, `255` = 255L, `258` = 258L, 
`261` = 261L, `265` = 265L, `267` = 267L, `270` = 270L, `273` = 273L, 
`277` = 277L, `279` = 279L, `287` = 287L, `299` = 299L, `302` = 302L, 
`306` = 306L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, `330` = 330L, `334` = 334L, 
`336` = 336L, `337` = 337L, `339` = 339L, `348` = 348L, `349` = 349L, 
`351` = 351L, `355` = 355L, `357` = 357L, `359` = 359L, `362` = 362L, 
`366` = 366L, `369` = 369L, `372` = 372L, `377` = 377L, `381` = 381L, 
`382` = 382L, `384` = 384L, `387` = 387L, `390` = 390L, `397` = 397L, 
`399` = 399L, `402` = 402L, `405` = 405L, `407` = 407L, `411` = 411L, 
`414` = 414L, `420` = 420L, `429` = 429L, `444` = 444L, `450` = 450L, 
`451` = 451L, `453` = 453L, `456` = 456L, `458` = 458L, `466` = 466L, 
`468` = 468L, `472` = 472L, `474` = 474L, `483` = 483L, `487` = 487L, 
`489` = 489L, `492` = 492L, `493` = 493L, `495` = 495L, `498` = 498L, 
`499` = 499L, `501` = 501L, `509` = 509L, `514` = 514L, `516` = 516L, 
`529` = 529L, `531` = 531L, `532` = 532L, `534` = 534L, `536` = 536L, 
`541` = 541L, `543` = 543L, `552` = 552L, `555` = 555L, `563` = 563L, 
`568` = 568L, `570` = 570L, `573` = 573L, `575` = 575L, `578` = 578L, 
`581` = 581L, `583` = 583L, `585` = 585L, `587` = 587L, `594` = 594L, 
`598` = 598L, `600` = 600L, `614` = 614L, `617` = 617L, `619` = 619L, 
`621` = 621L, `624` = 624L, `628` = 628L, `630` = 630L, `631` = 631L, 
`633` = 633L, `634` = 634L, `636` = 636L, `639` = 639L, `647` = 647L, 
`653` = 653L, `656` = 656L, `658` = 658L, `660` = 660L, `665` = 665L, 
`668` = 668L, `676` = 676L, `678` = 678L, `681` = 681L, `683` = 683L, 
`687` = 687L, `689` = 689L, `693` = 693L, `704` = 704L, `706` = 706L, 
`708` = 708L, `713` = 713L, `715` = 715L, `717` = 717L, `720` = 720L, 
`723` = 723L, `725` = 725L, `732` = 732L, `733` = 733L, `735` = 735L, 
`738` = 738L, `750` = 750L, `753` = 753L, `754` = 754L, `756` = 756L, 
`762` = 762L, `771` = 771L, `773` = 773L, `782` = 782L, `784` = 784L, 
`786` = 786L, `787` = 787L, `789` = 789L, `793` = 793L, `795` = 795L, 
`798` = 798L, `800` = 800L, `816` = 816L, `817` = 817L, `819` = 819L, 
`822` = 822L, `833` = 833L, `837` = 837L, `845` = 845L, `848` = 848L, 
`851` = 851L, `853` = 853L, `855` = 855L, `861` = 861L, `872` = 872L, 
`874` = 874L, `876` = 876L, `882` = 882L, `883` = 883L, `885` = 885L, 
`888` = 888L, `889` = 889L, `891` = 891L, `896` = 896L, `900` = 900L, 
`913` = 913L, `915` = 915L, `916` = 916L, `918` = 918L, `920` = 920L, 
`926` = 926L, `929` = 929L, `951` = 951L, `954` = 954L, `974` = 974L, 
`979` = 979L, `981` = 981L, `983` = 983L, `986` = 986L, `988` = 988L, 
`990` = 990L, `991` = 991L, `993` = 993L, `996` = 996L, `998` = 998L, 
`1002` = 1002L, `1010` = 1010L, `1017` = 1017L, `1021` = 1021L, 
`1023` = 1023L, `1027` = 1027L, `1029` = 1029L, `1042` = 1042L, 
`1044` = 1044L, `1050` = 1050L, `1054` = 1054L, `1056` = 1056L, 
`1058` = 1058L, `1064` = 1064L, `1073` = 1073L, `1077` = 1077L, 
`1078` = 1078L, `1080` = 1080L, `1090` = 1090L, `1092` = 1092L, 
`1095` = 1095L, `1101` = 1101L, `1116` = 1116L, `1119` = 1119L, 
`1122` = 1122L, `1126` = 1126L, `1128` = 1128L, `1132` = 1132L, 
`1134` = 1134L, `1138` = 1138L, `1140` = 1140L, `1143` = 1143L, 
`1144` = 1144L, `1146` = 1146L, `1158` = 1158L, `1160` = 1160L, 
`1164` = 1164L, `1166` = 1166L, `1170` = 1170L, `1172` = 1172L, 
`1174` = 1174L, `1176` = 1176L, `1180` = 1180L, `1182` = 1182L, 
`1184` = 1184L, `1186` = 1186L, `1188` = 1188L, `1190` = 1190L, 
`1201` = 1201L, `1203` = 1203L, `1206` = 1206L, `1212` = 1212L, 
`1213` = 1213L, `1215` = 1215L, `1218` = 1218L, `1221` = 1221L, 
`1225` = 1225L, `1227` = 1227L, `1233` = 1233L, `1235` = 1235L, 
`1241` = 1241L, `1245` = 1245L, `1247` = 1247L, `1251` = 1251L, 
`1259` = 1259L, `1262` = 1262L, `1265` = 1265L, `1267` = 1267L, 
`1269` = 1269L, `1272` = 1272L, `1275` = 1275L, `1281` = 1281L, 
`1286` = 1286L, `1289` = 1289L, `1292` = 1292L, `1301` = 1301L, 
`1303` = 1303L, `1305` = 1305L, `1310` = 1310L, `1314` = 1314L, 
`1323` = 1323L, `1326` = 1326L, `1342` = 1342L, `1344` = 1344L, 
`1347` = 1347L, `1358` = 1358L, `1361` = 1361L, `1366` = 1366L, 
`1368` = 1368L, `1370` = 1370L, `1373` = 1373L, `1379` = 1379L, 
`1388` = 1388L, `1390` = 1390L, `1392` = 1392L, `1394` = 1394L, 
`1396` = 1396L, `1398` = 1398L, `1401` = 1401L, `1403` = 1403L, 
`1406` = 1406L, `1411` = 1411L, `1413` = 1413L, `1420` = 1420L, 
`1422` = 1422L, `1424` = 1424L, `1427` = 1427L, `1429` = 1429L, 
`1431` = 1431L, `1435` = 1435L, `1437` = 1437L, `1439` = 1439L, 
`1443` = 1443L, `1449` = 1449L, `1455` = 1455L, `1457` = 1457L, 
`1461` = 1461L, `1469` = 1469L, `1471` = 1471L, `1473` = 1473L, 
`1478` = 1478L, `1480` = 1480L, `1482` = 1482L, `1483` = 1483L, 
`1485` = 1485L, `1487` = 1487L, `1491` = 1491L, `1496` = 1496L, 
`1501` = 1501L, `1503` = 1503L, `1506` = 1506L, `1507` = 1507L, 
`1509` = 1509L, `1511` = 1511L, `1515` = 1515L, `1521` = 1521L, 
`1525` = 1525L, `1527` = 1527L, `1529` = 1529L, `1531` = 1531L, 
`1533` = 1533L, `1534` = 1534L, `1536` = 1536L, `1539` = 1539L, 
`1556` = 1556L, `1566` = 1566L, `1575` = 1575L, `1578` = 1578L, 
`1579` = 1579L, `1581` = 1581L, `1584` = 1584L, `1587` = 1587L, 
`1595` = 1595L, `1598` = 1598L, `1604` = 1604L, `1611` = 1611L, 
`1615` = 1615L, `1617` = 1617L, `1618` = 1618L, `1620` = 1620L, 
`1624` = 1624L, `1626` = 1626L, `1632` = 1632L, `1633` = 1633L, 
`1635` = 1635L, `1637` = 1637L, `1640` = 1640L, `1642` = 1642L, 
`1644` = 1644L, `1646` = 1646L, `1649` = 1649L, `1653` = 1653L, 
`1657` = 1657L, `1659` = 1659L, `1660` = 1660L, `1662` = 1662L, 
`1667` = 1667L, `1671` = 1671L, `1673` = 1673L, `1676` = 1676L, 
`1678` = 1678L, `1680` = 1680L, `1684` = 1684L, `1686` = 1686L, 
`1689` = 1689L, `1698` = 1698L, `1705` = 1705L, `1707` = 1707L, 
`1709` = 1709L, `1714` = 1714L, `1716` = 1716L, `1730` = 1730L, 
`1732` = 1732L, `1734` = 1734L, `1740` = 1740L, `1742` = 1742L, 
`1747` = 1747L, `1749` = 1749L, `1752` = 1752L, `1753` = 1753L, 
`1755` = 1755L, `1764` = 1764L, `1769` = 1769L, `1774` = 1774L, 
`1776` = 1776L, `1782` = 1782L, `1783` = 1783L, `1785` = 1785L, 
`1790` = 1790L, `1792` = 1792L, `1794` = 1794L, `1797` = 1797L, 
`1800` = 1800L, `1803` = 1803L, `1806` = 1806L, `1810` = 1810L, 
`1812` = 1812L, `1817` = 1817L, `1822` = 1822L, `1824` = 1824L, 
`1828` = 1828L, `1830` = 1830L, `1833` = 1833L, `1849` = 1849L, 
`1851` = 1851L, `1856` = 1856L, `1859` = 1859L, `1863` = 1863L, 
`1866` = 1866L, `1871` = 1871L, `1874` = 1874L, `1878` = 1878L, 
`1879` = 1879L, `1881` = 1881L, `1884` = 1884L, `1890` = 1890L, 
`1897` = 1897L, `1899` = 1899L, `1902` = 1902L, `1904` = 1904L, 
`1907` = 1907L, `1914` = 1914L, `1915` = 1915L, `1917` = 1917L, 
`1918` = 1918L, `1920` = 1920L, `1923` = 1923L, `1927` = 1927L, 
`1929` = 1929L, `1932` = 1932L, `1935` = 1935L, `1939` = 1939L, 
`1941` = 1941L, `1947` = 1947L, `1948` = 1948L, `1950` = 1950L, 
`1951` = 1951L, `1953` = 1953L, `1958` = 1958L, `1961` = 1961L, 
`1968` = 1968L, `1974` = 1974L, `1975` = 1975L, `1977` = 1977L, 
`1979` = 1979L, `1982` = 1982L, `1985` = 1985L, `1988` = 1988L, 
`1996` = 1996L, `1998` = 1998L, `1999` = 1999L, `2001` = 2001L, 
`2010` = 2010L, `2012` = 2012L, `2020` = 2020L, `2022` = 2022L, 
`2026` = 2026L, `2028` = 2028L, `2032` = 2032L, `2034` = 2034L, 
`2039` = 2039L, `2044` = 2044L, `2046` = 2046L, `2052` = 2052L, 
`2054` = 2054L, `2056` = 2056L, `2058` = 2058L, `2063` = 2063L, 
`2066` = 2066L, `2072` = 2072L, `2076` = 2076L, `2079` = 2079L, 
`2082` = 2082L, `2084` = 2084L, `2086` = 2086L, `2088` = 2088L, 
`2091` = 2091L, `2093` = 2093L, `2097` = 2097L, `2098` = 2098L, 
`2100` = 2100L, `2104` = 2104L, `2106` = 2106L, `2107` = 2107L, 
`2109` = 2109L, `2111` = 2111L, `2114` = 2114L, `2126` = 2126L, 
`2136` = 2136L, `2142` = 2142L, `2144` = 2144L, `2146` = 2146L, 
`2148` = 2148L, `2153` = 2153L, `2160` = 2160L, `2162` = 2162L, 
`2165` = 2165L, `2170` = 2170L, `2172` = 2172L, `2173` = 2173L, 
`2175` = 2175L, `2180` = 2180L, `2182` = 2182L, `2184` = 2184L, 
`2186` = 2186L, `2189` = 2189L, `2191` = 2191L, `2193` = 2193L, 
`2198` = 2198L, `2200` = 2200L, `2202` = 2202L, `2205` = 2205L, 
`2207` = 2207L, `2210` = 2210L, `2212` = 2212L, `2214` = 2214L, 
`2215` = 2215L, `2217` = 2217L, `2220` = 2220L, `2221` = 2221L, 
`2223` = 2223L, `2225` = 2225L, `2229` = 2229L, `2232` = 2232L, 
`2234` = 2234L, `2236` = 2236L, `2238` = 2238L, `2239` = 2239L, 
`2241` = 2241L, `2245` = 2245L, `2247` = 2247L, `2249` = 2249L, 
`2251` = 2251L, `2253` = 2253L, `2262` = 2262L, `2264` = 2264L, 
`2268` = 2268L, `2270` = 2270L, `2274` = 2274L, `2279` = 2279L, 
`2288` = 2288L, `2292` = 2292L, `2296` = 2296L, `2298` = 2298L, 
`2304` = 2304L, `2308` = 2308L, `2310` = 2310L, `2313` = 2313L, 
`2321` = 2321L, `2324` = 2324L, `2327` = 2327L, `2329` = 2329L, 
`2331` = 2331L, `2334` = 2334L, `2336` = 2336L, `2339` = 2339L, 
`2342` = 2342L, `2344` = 2344L, `2346` = 2346L, `2348` = 2348L, 
`2350` = 2350L, `2352` = 2352L, `2353` = 2353L, `2355` = 2355L, 
`2358` = 2358L, `2361` = 2361L, `2365` = 2365L, `2367` = 2367L, 
`2373` = 2373L, `2375` = 2375L, `2381` = 2381L, `2384` = 2384L, 
`2387` = 2387L, `2391` = 2391L, `2393` = 2393L, `2395` = 2395L, 
`2397` = 2397L, `2399` = 2399L, `2401` = 2401L, `2403` = 2403L, 
`2405` = 2405L, `2410` = 2410L, `2412` = 2412L, `2413` = 2413L, 
`2415` = 2415L, `2423` = 2423L, `2425` = 2425L, `2427` = 2427L, 
`2429` = 2429L, `2435` = 2435L, `2437` = 2437L, `2439` = 2439L, 
`2442` = 2442L, `2444` = 2444L, `2446` = 2446L, `2448` = 2448L, 
`2449` = 2449L, `2451` = 2451L, `2455` = 2455L, `2457` = 2457L, 
`2462` = 2462L, `2466` = 2466L, `2467` = 2467L, `2469` = 2469L, 
`2474` = 2474L, `2479` = 2479L, `2481` = 2481L, `2483` = 2483L, 
`2485` = 2485L, `2487` = 2487L, `2496` = 2496L, `2498` = 2498L, 
`2500` = 2500L, `2502` = 2502L, `2507` = 2507L, `2509` = 2509L, 
`2511` = 2511L, `2514` = 2514L, `2518` = 2518L, `2520` = 2520L, 
`2522` = 2522L, `2524` = 2524L, `2526` = 2526L, `2528` = 2528L, 
`2530` = 2530L, `2532` = 2532L, `2533` = 2533L, `2535` = 2535L
), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: What happens when a date reaches 60? Are subsequent 'requests' for that date marked in any way? Presumably they can no longer add to the total?

Comment: Hi O.A., when a date has reached a value of 60 it cannot get any more participants added to that date or any value added to it. If another participant only has that date available as an option, that participant would get dropped off. Hope this answers your question?

Comment: @DebbieOomen I do not have time for the complete solution. Dates with ficol == 60 can no longer be booked (date_full <- df %>% filter(ficol == 60)). You can now check whether all bookings of a participant fall on these date. The next step would be to filter non-full days and high priority requests, date_v1 <- df %>% filter(ficol < 60, vis == "V1"), then group it by date and add a counter column, and then a cumsum column (recalling to multiply your counter by 2). Filter again for the cumsum < 60 which are your bookings. filter participants and dates from df and treat open V1 and V2 next, etc.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for this answer. I do not quite understand how to go from the date_full to your next step, check whether all bookings of a participant fall on these dates. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more.. thanks in advance!

Comment: `df %>% filter(date == "2021-11-23")` gives four visits on one day, is that correct?

Comment: Yes! And since there are already 60 ficols on that day, no additional visits can be permitted on 2021-11-23

Comment: have you checked the answer proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I suggest a slightly different strategy here.  Divide your data in two parts

- One having patients' preferences and allotted dates say `df1`.  This df I suggest you should have wider dataframe after `pivot_wider`.
- another having balance of appointments available for all given dates say `df2`

This way you'll have distiction (as against a longer df) that you'll know patient has been allocated which date.  Follow like this `for loop`.  It will simultaneosuly modify both `df1` and `df2`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = Included.y, names_from = vis, values_from = date, names_sort = T)
df2 <- df %>% select(date, ficol) %>% mutate(ficol = as.numeric(ficol),
                                      ficol = ifelse(is.na(ficol), 0, ficol),
                                      bal = (60 - ficol)/2) %>%
  unique() %>% arrange(date)



df1$allocated <- "dummy"

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))){
  if(!is.na(df1[i,2]) & df2[match(df1[i,2], df2$date), 3] > 0){
    df1[i, 5] <- "V1"
    df2[match(df1[i,2], df2$date), 3] <- df2[match(df1[i,2], df2$date), 3] -1
  } else if(!is.na(df1[i,3]) & df2[match(df1[i,3], df2$date), 3] > 0){
    df1[i, 5] <- "V2"
    df2[match(df1[i,3], df2$date), 3] <- df2[match(df1[i,3], df2$date), 3] -1
  } else if(!is.na(df1[i,4]) & df2[match(df1[i,4], df2$date), 3] > 0){
    df1[i, 5] <- "V3"
    df2[match(df1[i,4], df2$date), 3] <- df2[match(df1[i,4], df2$date), 3] -1
  } else{
    df1[i, 5] <- NA
  }
}

df1
# A tibble: 46 x 5
   Included.y V1         V2         V3         allocated
        <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>    
 1          1 2021-08-26 NA         2021-08-25 V1       
 2          3 2021-10-28 NA         2021-10-27 V1       
 3          4 2021-10-19 2021-10-20 2021-10-18 V1       
 4          5 2021-11-11 NA         2021-11-10 V1       
 5          6 2021-09-08 2021-09-09 2021-09-07 V1       
 6          7 2021-12-02 NA         2021-12-01 V1       
 7          8 2021-08-18 2021-08-19 2021-08-17 V1       
 8          9 2021-09-27 2021-09-28 NA         NA       
 9         12 2021-12-09 NA         2021-12-08 V1       
10         13 2021-07-06 2021-07-07 2021-07-05 V2       
# ... with 36 more rows

> df2
# A tibble: 62 x 3
   date       ficol   bal
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2021-07-05    60     0
 2 2021-07-06    60     0
 3 2021-07-07    24    17
 4 2021-07-13    60     0
 5 2021-07-14    16    20
 6 2021-07-15     0    30
 7 2021-07-19    60     0
 8 2021-07-20    32    13
 9 2021-07-21     0    30
10 2021-07-22     0    29
# ... with 52 more rows
```

If you still want output as shown above, do it thereafter

```
df %>% select(-ficol) %>% left_join(df2 %>% mutate(ficol = 60- 2* bal) %>% select(-bal), by = "date") %>%
  mutate(ficol = ifelse(ficol == 0, NA, ficol))

# A tibble: 100 x 4
   Included.y vis   date       ficol
        <int> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
 1          1 V1    2021-08-26     4
 2          1 V3    2021-08-25    44
 3          3 V1    2021-10-28     6
 4          3 V3    2021-10-27    60
 5          4 V1    2021-10-19    24
 6          4 V2    2021-10-20    NA
 7          4 V3    2021-10-18    60
 8          5 V1    2021-11-11     4
 9          5 V3    2021-11-10    NA
10          6 V1    2021-09-08    24
# ... with 90 more rows
```

As requested in comments, to get `allocated_date` do as follows

```
df1 %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(allocated_date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(allocated), NA_Date_, get(allocated))))

# A tibble: 46 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   Included.y V1         V2         V3         allocated allocated_date
        <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>     <date>        
 1          1 2021-08-26 NA         2021-08-25 V1        2021-08-26    
 2          3 2021-10-28 NA         2021-10-27 V1        2021-10-28    
 3          4 2021-10-19 2021-10-20 2021-10-18 V1        2021-10-19    
 4          5 2021-11-11 NA         2021-11-10 V1        2021-11-11    
 5          6 2021-09-08 2021-09-09 2021-09-07 V1        2021-09-08    
 6          7 2021-12-02 NA         2021-12-01 V1        2021-12-02    
 7          8 2021-08-18 2021-08-19 2021-08-17 V1        2021-08-18    
 8          9 2021-09-27 2021-09-28 NA         NA        NA            
 9         12 2021-12-09 NA         2021-12-08 V1        2021-12-09    
10         13 2021-07-06 2021-07-07 2021-07-05 V2        2021-07-07    
# ... with 36 more rows
```

Comment: Hi AnilGoyal, I keep getting an error in the for loop:`Error in if (!is.na(df1[i, 2]) & df2[match(df1[i, 2], df2$date), 3] >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` For loops are not my specialty at all so I don't know where it;s going wrong. To me the if statements seem perfectly fine

Comment: I had to change the NAs to 0 in df2 and then the loop didnt give me an error anymore. However, my df1 looks different than yours. For participant ID 1, V3 is the allocated choice, even though V1 does not have any value to start with..

Comment: Yes, If you'll check your column its of character type than of numeric. Still, in my output participant 1 is allocated V1 only and not V3

Comment: But Participant 1 has preferred choice later than V3 date and that's your logic

Comment: Yes so the chronoligcal order of dates does not matter.  The V1, V2 and V3 columns decide the preferrence of the dates. So for participant 1, the outcome in your output is correct, V3 is the last possibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231367/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-debbie-oomen).

Comment: just one more question regarding the output.
For all participants, I still have multiple dates available. So participant 1 still has V1 and V3 there, now i know from df1 that V1 is the allocated date but is it possible to only show the allocated date per participant? In the case of no allocated date, the participant can be dropped off